# converting a string json into Scala case class

Tags: json, scala

I know this kind of question has been answered so many times, but i could not find the answer to the error I am getting ::

I am trying to convert a string JSON into a case class in IntelliJ IDEA CE.

The code goes like this ::

```
package com.netflix.ist.gbi.application

import scala.io.Source
import scala.collection.mutable._
import org.json4s._
//import org.json4s.DefaultFormats
import com.netflix.ist.gbi.model.EventPayloadIn
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._

object ObjDataArchival extends App{
    val a : ListBuffer[String] = ListBuffer()
    for (line Source.fromFile("/Users/sankar.biswas/Desktop/jsonFile.json").getLines) {
       a.append(line)
       jsonStrToMap(line)
    }


    def jsonStrToMap(jsonStr: String) : EventPayloadIn = {
       implicit val formats : DefaultFormats.type = org.json4s.DefaultFormats
       parse(jsonStr).extract[EventPayloadIn]
    }


}
```

The case classes are defined in a scala file which has been imported.
but when I am running it, I am getting the below error ::

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Function0.$init$(Lscala/Function0;)V
at org.json4s.ThreadLocal.<init>(Formats.scala:348)
at org.json4s.DefaultFormats.$init$(Formats.scala:355)
at org.json4s.DefaultFormats$.<init>(Formats.scala:333)
at org.json4s.DefaultFormats$.<clinit>(Formats.scala)
at com.apple.ist.gbi.application.ObjDataArchival$.jsonStrToMap(ObjDataArchival.scala:21)
at com.apple.ist.gbi.application.ObjDataArchival$$anonfun$1.apply(ObjDataArchival.scala:16)
at com.apple.ist.gbi.application.ObjDataArchival$$anonfun$1.apply(ObjDataArchival.scala:13)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
at com.apple.ist.gbi.application.ObjDataArchival$.delayedEndpoint$com$apple$ist$gbi$application$ObjDataArchival$1(ObjDataArchival.scala:13)
at com.apple.ist.gbi.application.ObjDataArchival$delayedInit$body.apply(ObjDataArchival.scala:10)
at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)
at com.apple.ist.gbi.application.ObjDataArchival$.main(ObjDataArchival.scala:10)
at com.apple.ist.gbi.application.ObjDataArchival.main(ObjDataArchival.scala)
```

The error seems to be in this line ::

```
implicit val formats : DefaultFormats.type = org.json4s.DefaultFormats
```

I tried with similar lines like ::

```
implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
```

But could not resolve the issue in any way.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like below can work.

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._
import scala.io.Source

object JSONParsing extends App {


  implicit val formats = DefaultFormats // Brings in default date formats etc.

  case class BookDetails(bookId: String, bookName: String, authorName: String, authorCountry: String)

  for (line <- Source.fromFile("/Users/sankar.biswas/Desktop/jsonFile.json").getLines) {
    val bookDetails = jsonStrToMap(line)
    println(bookDetails)
  }

  def jsonStrToMap(jsonStr: String): BookDetails = {
    parse(jsonStr).camelizeKeys.extract[BookDetails]
  }
}
```

Content of `jsonFile` file :

```
{"book_id":"1","book_name":"Scala","author_name":"Edward","author_country":"Poland"}
{"book_id":"1","book_name":"Scala","author_name":"Edward","author_country":"Poland"}
{"book_id":"1","book_name":"Scala","author_name":"Edward","author_country":"Poland"}
{"book_id":"1","book_name":"Scala","author_name":"Edward","author_country":"Poland"}
```

**Update :**

build.sbt

```
  "org.json4s" %% "json4s-native" % "3.5.2",
  "org.json4s" %% "json4s-jackson" % "3.6.0"
```

Comment: Hi @KZapagol, thank you so much for taking the time, tried your suggestion but getting the same error, but while I am trying to run the code in Scala REPL, it is working fine, it has something to do with IntelliJ i suppose! still unable to figure the error out.

Comment: Hi..I also used IntelliJ and same code is working fine. Can you please share your case class structure and json content.

Comment: ok before sending the case class and content, let me inform you this that i have tried running the object "JSONParsing" which you have created in my IntelliJ as well, and i am getting the same error.

Comment: It's strange..did you use JSONParsing code as it is or modified something?Are you using same json file content?

Comment: Yes I am using the code as it is. I think it has something to do with the IntelliJ, or may be the version that i am using for different components are not compatible with each other!

Comment: I have used `"org.json4s" %% "json4s-native" % "3.5.2",
  "org.json4s" %% "json4s-jackson" % "3.6.0"` these versions. Please rebuild your project and try. The code has ran successfully now also. I am not able to paste screen shot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189756/discussion-between-kzapagol-and-sankar).